# Is there a jQuery function for finding the hover-count of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, hover, jquery-hover

I've an image which `id="logo"`. If someone hover on the image element, I'm hiding the image & at the same time displaying a sentence. Once someone do a mouseleave, the image is back to its own place and the sentence is gone.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Also I've three sentences in three separate `span`. If someone first time hovers on the image then I want to display the firs sentence, if someone hover over the image second time then want to display the second sentence, if hovers 3rd time then 3rd sentence. My code repo is [here](https://github.com/shihab0915/logo_animation). **Most clearly**, I want to achieve [this logo hover animation](https://www.marieforleo.com/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   
    var logo_img = $(".logo_container img");

    
        $(logo_img).hover(function() {
            $(logo_img).css("display", "none")
            $(".logo_container span.first").css("display", "block")
        },
        
        function(){
            $(logo_img).css("display", "block")
            $(".logo_container span.first").css("display", "none")
        });
    

});
```

```css
body{padding: 0 20px; font-family: "Gotham A", "Gotham B", sans-serif;}

.logo_container a{text-decoration: none; color: #2F2F2F;}

.logo_container img, .logo_container span{display: inline-block;}

.logo_container img{
    max-width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}

.logo_container .slogan{font-size: 1.5rem; position: relative; top: 10px;}

.logo_container span.slogan{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo_container">
            
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shihab0915/logo_animation/master/img/logo.png" id="logo" >
                    <span class="slogan first">first sentence</span>
                    <span class="slogan second">second sentence</span> 
                    <span class="slogan third">third sentence</span>                             
                </a>            
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: I doubt there's a jQuery-specific thing to help you here. Seems like you just need some basic JS to keep track of hover count. You've already got the hover event handling in place, now you just need to check the count and display the appropriate message. Even simpler, I'd consider a pop/push approach. Simply put each message in an array and on hover display the popped message and then push it back onto the array. This way you don't have to keep track of anything.

Comment: Edit to my previous comment: I should have said pop/unshift (pop the last and unshift it to the start of the array)

Comment: You could just increment a counter on each hover event and show one of the the 3 different `<span>` elements based on the remainder from dividing by 3: `(counter % 3)`.

Comment: Trying to figuire it out what you said. Thank you @BradEvans Romen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to show only the first `.slogan` on hover (using css) and have JS switch the order of the `.slogan`s on mouseleave.

EG:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".logo_container").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("#slogans .slogan:first").appendTo($("#slogans"));
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-family: "Gotham A", "Gotham B", sans-serif;
}

.logo_container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2F2F2F;
}

.logo_container img,
.logo_container span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo_container img {
  max-width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}

.logo_container .slogan {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  margin: 12px 0;
}

.logo_container:hover #logo {
  display: none;
}

.logo_container span.slogan {
  display: none;
}

.logo_container:hover span.slogan:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo_container">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shihab0915/logo_animation/master/img/logo.png" id="logo" />
        <span id="slogans">
          <span class="slogan">first sentence</span>
          <span class="slogan">second sentence</span>
          <span class="slogan">third sentence</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Classic SO. Somehow moving things around in the DOM is better than not? okee

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is a rather simple approach to the problem. I've only posted the JS and the HTML since I didn't change any CSS. This approach simply changes the text itself as opposed to showing/hiding different elements.

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/bradevans/pen/MWYGjgo)

JS:

```
var messagesObj = {};

$(document).ready(function(){

  messagesObj.messages = ['message one', 'message two', 'message three'];

  var logo_img = $(".logo_container img");

  $(logo_img).mouseover(function() {
    messagesObj.current = messagesObj.messages.pop();
    $('.message').text(messagesObj.current);
  });

  $(logo_img).mouseout(function() {
      messagesObj.messages.unshift(messagesObj.current);
    $('.message').text('');
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo_container">

                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shihab0915/logo_animation/master/img/logo.png" id="logo" >                       
                </a>            
                <span class="message"></span> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```